# Do I need a VAO for each different object rendered?

Tags: c++, opengl

I believe I misunderstood the limits of VAO's.

I have 3 VAO's, one for each vertex spec. format.

Focusing on the VAO intended for menus/quads rendering in homogeneous screen coordinates, how many buffers can I have connected to the same array index of a single VAO ?

Due to results in my program I am inclined to believe every separate instance rendered should have it's own VAO.  However, I am still able to draw two instances using one VAO, although with incorrect results.  (Cursor takes up fullscreen and position doesn't change, rendered overtop fullscreen TitleMenu).

I'm fairly certain I already know the answer is have a VAO for each instance with differing array buffer data, would just like confirmation I have rationalized this correctly.

Also, are the buffers bound to the VAO copied to the VAO and can be deleted?

Does a glVertexAttribPointer() need to be called again to update the information in a VAO ?  Or is buffering data to the original buffer sufficient ?

Comment: yes, one VAO for each instance with different array buffer data. According to the spec the buffers can be deleted (if the VAO is not bound during deletion) as the buffers are reference counted. Unfortunately what is supposed to happen and what actually happens is often different (drivers have bugs) so it's best not to delete the buffers until you're actually done with them.

Comment: So if I bind the VAO and buffer data using the same buffer, this will affect the buffer stored in the VAO ?

If I am rendering 1000's of the same instance, can I just have 1 VAO storing 1 copy of vertex/uv/normal bufferdata and a 4th array of position data for each one ?

Comment: VAOs just store references to buffers. They don't copy the buffers.

Comment: You can of course put a bunch of objects in one buffer